# Prove or Disprove Subset and Powerset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working on a problem but I need additional feedback to see if its correct. I'm trying to figure out if....

$$P(A \cup B) ⊆  P(A) \cup P(B) \cup P(A \cap B)$$

Where power set is denoted by P.
I used A = {1,2,3}  and B = {2,4}. I did all the power sets for each of the following. And I came up that this in fact is disproved because from $P(A \cup B)$ there exists {2,4} that only exists in $P(B)$ but not in $P(A)$ or $P(A \cap B)$. Am i correct to assume that the above statement is disproved and incorrect???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the statement is indeed false, your counterexample is incorrect: the set $\{2, 4\}$ is an element of $\mathcal P(B)$ and therefore also of $\mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B) \cup \mathcal P(A \cap B)$.

Try considering, for example, $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$. Can you find a set which lies in $\mathcal P(A \cup B)$ but not in $\mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B) \cup \mathcal P(A \cap B)$?

Comment: Would that be {1,2} that doesn't exist??

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.

An even simpler example to see why you are correct is $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$.